# Help me improve this autohotkey scipt that copies text and sends to another application

Tags: autohotkey

I made an AutoHotKey script that does the following on an <kbd>Alt</kbd> + Click:

- Double-clicks on the current position
- Selects a word
- Copies the word to the clipboard
- Activates a second program
- Pastes the word into the program (a dictionary)
- Presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>

The problem is that it sometimes works in 80-90% of applications - in others it will work much less, sometimes only getting as far as pasting the text but not pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Below is the script so far, any ideas how to get it fully working?

```
!LButton::
IfWinExist PCD 
{
    Click 2
    Send, ^c
    WinActivate PCD
    WinWaitActive, PCD
    Send, ^v
    Send {Enter}
}
return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe the problem is a delay of the double click action (any mouse action has a default 10milisecond delay), you could add a sleep 20 or more after that line. Other thing is that SendInput is more faster than Send so you could try with this code:

```
!LButton::
IfWinExist PCD 
{
    Click 2
    sleep 50
    SendInput, ^c
    WinActivate PCD
    WinWaitActive, PCD
    SendInput, ^v{Enter}
}
return
```